When does $F(F^{-1}(p))=p$ fail, where $F$ is a CDF?
We define the inverse of a CDF $F$ as $$F^{-1}(p)=\inf\{x:F(x)\ge p\},\quad p\in(0,1).$$
It is easy to see that $F(F^{-1}(p))\ge p$ since $F^{-1}(p)$ satisfies the condition that $F(x)\ge p$. I am interested in the scenario when $F(F^{-1}(p))=p$.
Trivially, it holds when $F$ is continuous at $p$. However, is it necessarily false when $F$ is not continuous at $p$?

E.g. let $F(x)=1$ if $x\geq0$ and $F(x)=0$ otherwise. Then it is a CDF. For every $p\in(0,1)$ we get $F^{-1}(p)=0$.

What is true is $p=F(F^{-1} (p))$ for all $p$ implies $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

I think you mean "when $F$ is continuous at $F^{-1}(p)$".
